# Problema de imagenes en HTML y CSS!

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Me acaban de dar para realizar la siguiente página web. Ahora yo realice la página y tengo tres errores, notables, quizás hay mas pero no me doy cuenta

[Actividad](https://xd.adobe.com/spec/bb8bf45f-b3b9-431b-42fe-de4facfc0263-cdba/screen/956b36a1-d50f-41ca-8831-3c6374cc331e/M-vil-Android-1/)

Acá les dejo el link de mi página hasta el momento:

[Página prueba](https://jolly-bardeen-b2f2c1.netlify.com/)

Los tres problemas que tengo, son:

1. Simulando viendo desde una pantalla grande la imagen de arriba no se ve responsive, se ve mal.
2. Simulando viendo desde pantalla de un celular las dos imágenes se ven mal.
3. Simulando viendo desde pantalla de un celular la imagen del footer, no se centra.

Aca les dejo el código Html donde ubico las tres imágenes, de arriba.

```
<header class="doble">
    <div class="site-header"></div>
    <div class="site-mobile"></div>
</header>
```

Y aca les dejo todo lo relacionado a dichas clases en lo que es el css, "doble", "site-header" y "site-mobile".

```
.site-header{
background-position: center center;
background-size: cover;
min-height: 80rem;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;}

.site-mobile{
background-position: center center;
background-size: cover;    
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;}

@media (max-width: 768px) {

.site-header{
    background-image: url(../img/logo\ bbcos@2x.png); 
   }
.site-mobile{
    background-image: url(../img/logo2.png);
    min-height: 60rem;}
    }
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.site-header{
    background-image: url(../img/logocompleto.png);
    max-width: 100%;}        
}
```

> Aclaro, que la clase "doble" no la utilicé, la cree pensando usar desde ahi pero si no ignorenla.

Y aca les dejo el HTML de la parte del footer

```
<footer class="site-footer contenedor">
    <div>
        <img class="imagen imagen-footer" src="img/logos cc hair pro.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="cr">
        <p>Importa, distribuye y comercializa en forma exclusiva en todo el territorio de la República Argentina.</p> 

        <p>General Alvear 280 - Córdoba (5000) - Pcia. Córdoba - Argentina.
        </p>
    </div>        
</footer>
```

Y el CSS de la parte del footer:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .imagen-footer{
        float: right;
    }
    .site-footer{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
        grid-column-gap: 2rem;
        margin-top: 16.6rem;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .site-footer{        
        margin-top: 7.5rem;
    }

    .cr p{
        text-align: center;
    }
    .imagen-footer{
        display: inline-block;
        justify-content: center;
    }
}

.cr p{
    display: block;
    margin-block-start: 0!important;
    width: 41.8rem;
}
```

Les agrego el contenedor de la parte del CSS aunque creo que es innecesario:

```
.contenedor {
    width: 95%;
    max-width: 120rem; /** = 1200px **/
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

> Utilice HTML y CSS en los 'site-header' y 'site-mobile', porque desconozco como usar JavaScript u otra solucion, tengo entendido que hubiera sido mas facil con JS pero no lo se usar.

Comment: En ves de colocar dentro de una cabecera la imagen, prueba el colocarlo en un DIV posterior a ello utiliza el IMG con las clases tipo: width:100% para ajustar según el ancho del dispositivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero que esto te sirva :)

Para el punto 1 y 2 deberias agregar a las imagenes el tamañano de la img al 100%, seria agregar background-size (tamaño de la img) y background-repeat (para que la imagen no se repita) ejemplo:

```
    .site-header {
background-image: url(../img/logo\ bbcos@2x.png);
background-size: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

de esta forma las imagenes se adaptar a cualquier ancho y es responsive.

Para el punto 3 deberias agregar text-align: center al div que contiene la imagen.

Otra cosa que vi por si te sirve le deberias sacer el ancho fijo a los textos para que no se te corten en mobile y que estos se ajusten al ancho, ejemplo en el footer:

```
    .cr p {
display: block;
margin-block-start: 0!important;
width: 41.8rem; // esto lo deberias sacar en mobile ya que si lo dejas no te va 
 a centrar el texto
}
```

Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias Romina! Me sirvió!

Answer (score 0):

**DESKTOP**

En primer lugar, yo no pondría la imagen de cabecera como fondo de un **div**, ya que de esta forma es más dificil ajustarla para que sea responsive; por un lado tienes que ajustar la imagen de fondo y por otra el alto del contenedor, estando obligado a definir un alto fijo, ya que el contenedor tiene fondo pero no contenido.

Si utilizas la etiqueta **img** te será mucho más sencillo.

**MOBILE**

Si lo haces igual que con desktop, utilizando etiquetas **img** en vez de definir backgrounds en un bloque **div**, te será mucho más sencillo adaptarlas.

**FOOTER MOBILE**

Para que el footer aparezca centrado, tienes que asignarle el código que lo centre al contenedor en el que está alojada la imagen del footer y no a la misma imagen. De esta forma, añadiendo "text-align: center;" al **div** que contiene la **img** del footer, esta se centrará.

Comment: "Si utilizas la etiqueta img te será mucho más sencillo."  Habia probado de esa forma, utilizando IMG pero no se como hacer para que aparezca la imagen completa cuando este desde una CPU y desaparezca, cuando este desde un celular y aparezcan las otras dos imágenes.

Comment: Lo del **FOOTER MOBILE** me sirvió.

Comment: Muchas gracias Daniel, fue muy útil tu respuesta.